# Making a font awesome badge like icon combination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

In the tutorials, it shows you how to make an fa-stack for icons that are one on top of the other.  What I am looking for is making a increase font/decrease font icon, which fit in the same footprint as a bootstrap button group.  Here is a jsfiddle with what I have tried.

Note: In attempt 1 the buttons are too big, and in attempt 2 the icons are too small

https://jsfiddle.net/6k1uexor/1/

```
<div class="group">
Attempt 1
<div class="btn-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="fa-stack">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
Attempt 2
<div class="btn-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bonus Points if the + and minus symbols are like badges in the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using position absolute on the button and position relative on the one I wanted to be a badge.

https://jsfiddle.net/6k1uexor/2/

```
<div class="group">
Final Attempt
<div class="btn-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-hasbadge">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus fa-badge"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-hasbadge">
                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-badge"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn.btn-hasbadge {
  position:relative;
  padding-left:8px;
  padding-right:16px;
}

.fa-badge {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
           <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-minus fa-sm"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
           <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-plus fa-sm"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css,

```
.fa-sm{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vxbfc1ye/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This gets it done for a badge in the upper right. It's not working here but it should on your machine.

```css
.facustom-badge {
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 8px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-id-badge fa-stack-1x"/>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-stack-1x facustom-badge"/>
</span>
```